# Как обработать ошибку в телеграмм боте?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, python-3.6

Отправляю боту файл следующей конструкцией:

```
doc = 'D:\document.txt'
docc = open(doc, 'rb')
bot.send_document(command.chat.id, docc)
```

Но бот отваливается, если файл не удается найти. Каким образом корректно обработать данное исключение, вроде отправки сообщения, что файл не был найден?

Comment: `try-except` с соответствующим исключением.

Comment: Спасибо. Глупость сморозил)